# Why can/should we use 5 instead of 10?

Tags: calculus, optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, median

Problem:

> A pharmacy has a uniform annual demand for 200 bottles of a certain antibiotic. It costs \$10 per year for a storage place for one bottle, and $40 to place an order. How many times during the year should the pharmacy order the antibiotic in order to minimise total cost?

$ $

> Example 1: If you use 4 orders of 50 bottles each you need 50 storage places.

Cost of ordering is $4(40) = 160$

Total Cost is $4(40)+50(10)= 660$

> Example 2: If you use 10 orders for 20 bottles each, you need only 20 storage places, but it costs more to order:

Cost of ordering is $10(40) = 400 > 160$

Total Cost is $10(40)+20(10) = 600$

It seems that we must minimize

$$C(x,y) = 10x+40y$$

s.t. $200=xy$

I can change it to one variable, use Lagrange or something.

My professor gave this hint:

> Use \$5 per storage place instead of $10. The reasoning is that some bottles will get used right away, and some need to be stored the full time.

Something like 5 is the median of 0 and 10.

So apparently

$$C(x,y) = \color{red}{5}x+40y$$

Why?

Note: The minimisations will be different:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimise+5x%2B40(200%2Fx)
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimise+10x%2B40(200%2Fx)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter What do you mean by 'these' ? There is supposed to be one problem given above and a hint whose 'reasoning' is kind of unclear

Comment: There are two different problems at stake here: (i) There is your own interpretation, namely that one has to pay only for the maximal necessary number of pigeon holes, and (ii) there is the interpretation of your professor. In the latter the cost of actual storage time (e.g. for cooling) is an issue. The results we be different.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Which one is my interpretation? Sorry for any confusion. The examples are also given from my prof

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your inventory is depleted linearly (at a constant rate), you will make an order, which will put $x$ bottles in your inventory, it will deplete down to 0, and you reorder, to fill your inventory back up to $x$ (the order is immediately filled), and the cycle repeats.

When the inventory is full, you're paying to store $x$ items, but when it starts getting low, you're only paying to store fewer items.

Since the inventory drops at a constant rate, the average number of bottles of pills in your inventory at any given time will be half of x. Think about it: for the first half of the time you're using an inventory it's above half capacity, then the second half is below half capacity (and decreasing in a straight line). So, on average, the inventory cost is actually $10\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, or $5x$.

Your total cost is $C(x,y) = 5x + 40y$ because you have to pay the average storage cost (\$5) for each item in the inventory and pay \$40 for each order you make. You'll make $\frac{200}{x} orders, so you just need to minimize

\begin{align}
C(x) = 5x + \frac{8000}{x}
\end{align}

so that

\begin{align}
C'(x) = 5 - \frac{8000}{x^2}
\end{align}

Then we can minimize as

\begin{align}
5 - \frac{8000}{x^2} &= 0
\\5 &= \frac{8000}{x^2}
\\5x^2 &= 8000
\\x^2 &= 1600
\\x &= 40
\end{align}

so you should make 5 orders of 40 items each per year.

Comment: Is there any indication of linear depletion? Is such linearity precisely the justification of the 'reasoning' for the hint?

Comment: @BCLC I think the "uniform" part of the first sentence of the description implies this linearity; you need a bottle available at time $0.005n$, where $n=1,2,\dots,200$ and time is measured in years.

Comment: Ah right missed that. Thanks. Don't get it though. so i need a bottle available at times $t = \frac{1}{200}, \frac{2}{200}, ..., \frac{199}{200}, 1$ where $t$ is measured in years? You said 'you will make an order, which will put x bottles in your inventory, it will deplete down to 0' --> Do you mean we order at time, say, $\frac{1}{200}$, get the $x$ bottles at time $\frac{1}{200}$ and then have the x bottles depleted at time $\frac{2}{200}$ just in time to order and get $x$ more bottles at time $\frac{2}{200}$? Just after time $\frac{1}{200}$, the average bottles in my inventory is $x/2$.

Comment: Just after time $\frac{2}{200}$, the average bottles in my inventory is...still $x/2$? I think it is $(0+x+x)/3=2x/3$? Or should it be $(0+x+0+x)/4=2x/4 = x/2$? Wait, so what if the average amount of bottles at any times $t = \frac{1}{200}, \frac{2}{200}, ..., \frac{199}{200}, 1$ is $x/2$? That's assuming all the bottles are depleted before the new ones come in? Wait, what? There are exactly $x$ bottles in storage at any given $t = \frac{1}{200}, \frac{2}{200}, ..., \frac{199}{200}, 1$, right? What does the average matter?

Comment: @Ian ? (sorry thought mach replied)

Comment: I believe the assumption is that the order is immediately filled (or at least you will order ahead of time sufficiently such that the new inventory will arrive at times 1/200, 2/200, ...

Answer (score 1):

If you buy as soon as you completely run out of inventory (you can prove that it is always better to do this, since orders take no time), then your number of bottles stored in each cycle can be interpolated as $N-200t$, where $N$ is the order size and $t$ is the time since the last order in years. The average of this over an order period is $N/2$. You can check by integrating if you want, or you can just think about the area of a triangle. Ultimately, over one order period you wind up paying $N/2$ times $\$10$ times the time in between orders (in years). Adding up the cost over a full year cancels out the factor of the time, leaving a total cost of $\$5N$ for the storage cost.

The actual number may be slightly different from this. There is a correction associated to the discreteness of the removal of the bottles from storage, and when exactly that takes place. (The formulation above turns the number of bottles into a continuous variable which decreases continuously over time, to make the calculation easier.) There could be another correction if the optimum value of $N$ that we compute here does not evenly divide into $200$. (With these numbers it actually does, but one can easily tweak the numbers to make this not happen.) But these are small corrections, and are probably smaller than more fundamental problems with the model (such as the assumption that orders are paid for and then instantaneously delivered and the assumption that the orders come at exactly uniform times).

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'll try to process that later. Is your $N$ equal to my $x$?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Before I process this is, is it indeed wrong to try to minimise $C = 10x+40y$ ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, it is, because as your professor's hint clarifies, you sell bottles in between orders, which lowers the storage costs. Using $10$ instead of $5$ basically amounts to saying that you are paying for a "warehouse" of a given capacity, rather than for storing each bottle individually.

Comment: How do you know 'orders take no time' ? What is the triangle exactly? What is t? What is the problem if $N$ does not evenly divide into 200?

Comment: @BCLC 1. If you're not told how long the orders take to arrive then I would think that you should assume that they arrive instantaneously. 2. You're looking at average value of $N-200t$ from $t=0$ up to the value of $t$ where this is zero (since it is at this time that you place another order). This is a right triangle of height $N$ and some base length $b$. So its area is $Nb/2$. So the average is that divided by $b$, which is $N/2$. 3. I said this above.

Comment: @BCLC 4. If your orders are all the same size $N$ then you will make $200/N$ of them. If $N$ doesn't divide evenly into 200 then this says to make a non-integer number of orders. But in the real world we can't do that. So if the optimum turned out that way, then you would have to make orders of slightly different sizes instead. (You might try doing the problem again with $200$ replaced by $199$ to see this happen).

Comment: Ian, I mean is t the same t as with Mach?

Comment: @BCLC The scale is the same, but the $t$ that I talked about in my answer is just the time within one order cycle. So it runs from 0 to $N/200$, then "resets" back to 0 for the next order cycle. (You can of course extend everything appropriately, obtaining the number of bottles in storage at any time during the year, which is periodic). The $t$ I talked about in my comment runs from $0$ to $1$.